# <div> covering background image

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a fixed background image in CSS that is in a separate  above a content div. However for some reason the content div has a background that I cant seem to get rid of, therefore overlapping onto the background image.

**Please note

Here is the html:

```
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="content clear"> 
    <br> 
    <br>
    <br>
        <?php 
            $section = $_GET["section"];
            if ($section == 'changePassword'){
                include "changePassword.php";
            }
        ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.background {
    background-image: url('../assets/19.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
.clear {
    background: transparent;
    position: initial;
}
```

Comment: Try : **background-size:cover;**

Comment: Perhaps try using `background: none;` instead of `transparent`? Also, `initial` is not a valid value for [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).  You're probably looking for `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a separate div for the background image? Just use the body tag:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../assets/19.jpg');
}
```

That should greatly simplify your CSS, and potentially fix your problem.

Comment: The background image is supposed to remain fixed in relation to the scrollable content. Wouldn't this solution cause the content to remain fixed as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **background-image:none** for the div.

```
.clear {
    background-image:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are approaching this the wrong way. To add a fixed css background image you should use code like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="content clear"> 
<br> 
<br>
<br>
    <?php 
        $section = $_GET["section"];
        if ($section == 'changePassword'){
            include "changePassword.php";
        }
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
    background: url('../assets/19.jpg') no-repeat fixed ;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    position: initial;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you say

```
<div class="content clear">
```

yet your CSS is named

```
.clear
```

this doesn't match the name of the div, therefore will do nothing to the div, try this:

```
<div class="content">
```

and

```
.content{
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
```

Comment: I think he is using multiple classes into a single element whichis fine

Comment: that's not clear, so maybe, but the background issue should be solved from the code provided, and as someone else pointed out, 
    position:inital; is incorrect